# Cross Correlation in .NET

Tags: vb.net

I am working on an app that takes two audio channels and compares them to find the phase difference (delay). I came across this post;

[Calculating FFT Correlation Coefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988535/calculating-fft-correlation-coefficient)

which refers to this sample code;

https://dotnetfiddle.net/1nWIgQ

I got the code working with correct results after translating it to VB.NET (its the language I started with years ago in this app).

The problem I see is that when I change the signal generated from random noise to a sine wave, then the code gives crazy unrelated results. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Code below;

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports AForge.Math 'NuGet Package Aforge.Math module
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim c = New Xcorr4_2()
        Dim size As Integer = 2048
        Dim delay As Double

        delay = 2
        Dim signal1 = c.GenerateSignal(size)
        Dim signal2 = c.GenerateSignal(size, delay)

        Dim signal1Complex = c.ToComplexWithPadding(signal1, 2)
        Dim fftSignal1 = c.FFT(signal1Complex)

        Dim signal2Complex = c.ToComplexWithPadding(signal2, 2)
        Dim fftSignal2 = c.FFT(signal2Complex)

        Dim cc = c.CorrelationCoefficient(fftSignal1.ToArray(), fftSignal2.ToArray())
        MsgBox(cc.Item1) 'correlation coeff
        MsgBox(cc.Item2) 'recovered delay

    End Sub
End Class
Class Xcorr4_2

    Public Function CrossCorrelation(ByVal ffta As Complex(), ByVal fftb As Complex()) As Complex()
        Dim conj = ffta.[Select](Function(i) New Complex(i.Re, -i.Im)).ToArray()
        conj = conj.Zip(fftb, Function(v1, v2) Complex.Multiply(v1, v2)).ToArray()
        FourierTransform.FFT(conj, FourierTransform.Direction.Backward)

        Dim rr As Double() = New Double(conj.Length - 1) {}
        rr = conj.[Select](Function(i) i.Magnitude).ToArray()

        Return conj
    End Function

    Public Function CorrelationCoefficient(ByVal ffta As Complex(), ByVal fftb As Complex()) As Tuple(Of Double, Integer)
        Dim tuble As Tuple(Of Double, Integer)
        Dim correlation = CrossCorrelation(ffta, fftb)
        Dim seq = correlation.[Select](Function(i) i.Magnitude)
        Dim maxCoeff = seq.Max()
        Dim maxIndex As Integer = seq.ToList().IndexOf(maxCoeff)
        tuble = New Tuple(Of Double, Integer)(maxCoeff, maxIndex)
        Return tuble
    End Function

    Public Function FFT(ByVal signal As Complex()) As Complex()
        FourierTransform.FFT(signal, FourierTransform.Direction.Forward)
        Return signal
    End Function

    Public Function IFFT(ByVal signal As Complex()) As Complex()
        FourierTransform.FFT(signal, FourierTransform.Direction.Backward)
        Return signal
    End Function

    Public Function ToComplexWithPadding(ByVal sample As Double(), ByVal Optional padding As Integer = 1) As Complex()
        Dim logLength As Double = Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(sample.Length * padding, 2.0))
        Dim paddedLength As Integer = CInt(Math.Pow(2.0, Math.Min(Math.Max(1.0, logLength), 14.0)))
        Dim complex As Complex() = New Complex(paddedLength - 1) {}
        Dim samples = sample.ToArray()
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        While i < sample.Length
            complex(i) = New Complex(samples(i), 0)
            i += 1
        End While

        While i < paddedLength
            complex(i) = New Complex(0, 0)
            i += 1
        End While

        Return complex
    End Function

    Public Function GenerateSignal(ByVal size As Integer, ByVal Optional shift As Integer = 0) As Double()
        Dim list As List(Of Double) = New List(Of Double)()
        Dim generator = New AForge.Math.Random.StandardGenerator()

        ' Changed original random signal to Sine wave below
        For i As Integer = 0 To size - 1
            'Dim randomNumber As Double = generator.[Next]()
            'list.Add(randomNumber)
            list.Add(Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI / 200 * i + shift))
        Next

        Dim list2 As List(Of Double) = New List(Of Double)()

        For i As Integer = 0 To shift - 1
            list2.Add(0)
        Next

        Dim ar = list.ToArray()

        For i As Integer = 0 To size - shift - 1
            list2.Add(ar(i))
        Next

        Return list2.ToArray()
    End Function
End Class
```

Below is the output for original code vs the modified code with sine wave.

[Original code random signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rd5V.jpg)

[Modified with sine wave inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGMX2.jpg)

Comment: What is the purpose of adding `shift` zeroes to `list2`? The name "shift" makes me think it should be shifted, not delayed, e.g. something like `For i = 0 size -1` `list2.Add(list((i + shift) mod size))` `Next`.

Comment: I believe the original author wanted to shift the original signal by a certain delay value and then pad the rest of the shifted signal by zeros. In the end, Signal1 & Signal2 have the same buffer length to process the FFT's.

Comment: added sample screenshot of results